# Editing and reopening a closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

There is a question that was posed back in January that wasn't well formed but which had the bones of a very good question in it. You can see it [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/27346/tall-mans-bike-which-manufacturers?rq=1), it is closed now. I'm wondering, can/should it be resurrected by editing the question, or would it be better to start a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either option is fine. If it's closed but fixable, then editing it and getting it resurrected is good. It's also fine if you just ask your own new question.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of resurrecting it and preserving the work of the people who have already replied. Is there anything special that needs to be done to get it "un-closed" or is there something automagic that happens?

Comment: Editing gets it into the "evaluate for reopening" queue.

Comment: Automagic :-) Thanks.